# Do Equidistant points form a Geodesic in the Torus?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, geodesic

Consider the Torus $T \subseteq \Bbb R ^3$ seen as a revolution surface, around the $y$ axis, of a circle in the $xy$ plane given by the equation $(x-R)^2+y^2=r^2$, with $R>r>0$. We name $d_l$ the intrinsic metric of the torus, a.k.a. the geodesic distance. Given two points $p,q \in T$, I want to know if the set of equidistant points
$$\{v \in T : d_l(v,p)=d_l(v,q) \}$$
contains the image of a geodesic curve. I tried to make some calculations, but things got messy pretty fast. Acording to [this](http://www.rdrop.com/%7Ehalf/math/torus/torus.geodesics.pdf), let $F:[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi] \rightarrow T$ be the map
$$F(\phi,\theta)=(\ (R+r \cdot \cos\theta)\cdot \cos\phi\ , \ (R+r \cdot \cos \theta)\cdot \sin\phi \ , \ r \cdot \sin\theta\ )$$

If $h$ is a real number with $|h|\leq R+r$ and $\sigma(t)=F(\mu(t),t)$ is a curve where
$$\mu '(t)= \frac{r\cdot h}{(R+r\cdot \cos t)\cdot \sqrt{(R+r\cdot \cos t)^2-h^2}}$$
Then the reparametrization of $\sigma$ by arc leangth is a geodesic. Moreover, every geodesic can be obtained this way (at least locally). With this at hand, I tried to calculate the distance between two points in the torus, say $F(0,0)$ and $F(\phi_0, \theta_0)$. If $\sigma$ is as above, then
$$\Vert \sigma '(t)\Vert = \frac{r\cdot (R+r\cdot\cos t)}{\sqrt{(R+r \cdot \cos t)^2-h^2}}$$
Where $h$ is...some smart number that depends on $\phi_0,\theta_0$ (and I don't know how to calculate). Anyway, I coludn't get much further. This expression probably can't be integrated and I don't know how to go on.

Comment: For a flat torus the answer is positive (for arbitrary points $p, q$), but your torus is not flat. You should clarify if you are asking about this property **for all** or **for some** pairs of distinct points on the torus. In the 2nd case the answer will be positive while in the 1st case, most likely not. More importantly, is there a reason for asking about tori of revolution?

Comment: What I wanted to know was if, over a Riemannian surface $S$, the set $\{ x \in S : d(x,p)=d(x,q) \} $ contains the graph of a geodesic for every $p,q \in S$, beeing $d$ the intrinsic metric. This is true for the plane and for the sphere, so the following "easy" example I wanted to check was the Torus.

Comment: Are you looking for an equation to describe the geodesic?

Comment: Not exactly, but might be usefull

Comment: That's definitely false for arbitrary Riemannian surfaces.

Comment: Oh, how sad. Im looking for an counterexample tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a class of counter-examples:

Suppose that $M$ is a (not necessarily complete) connected Riemannian surface such that any two points of the universal cover of $M$ can be connected by a unique geodesic. Then the following are equivalent:

(a) the bisector of every geodesic segment in $M$ contains a (nondegenerate) geodesic subsegment.

(b) $M$ has constant curvature.

For instance, this applies if $M$ is a complete Riemannian manifold of curvature $\le 0$.

This can be derived from Theorems 46.1 and 47.4 in

*Busemann, Herbert*, The geometry of geodesics, Mineola, NY: Dover Publications (ISBN 0-486-44237-3). x, 422 p. (2005). [ZBL1141.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1141.53001).

In particular:

Suppose that $M$ is an arbitrary Riemannian surface and $m\in M$ any  point. Let $U$ be a convex neighborhood of $m$ in $M$ (it always exists). Then $U$ has constant curvature if and only if for every two points $p, q\in U$ the bisector of $pq$ contains a nondegenerate subsegment **contained in $U$**.

In other words, the statement you are looking for **always fails locally** except for metrics of constant curvature.

Actually, Busemann works in a much greater generality of G-spaces (which are metric spaces satisfying certain conditions).

---

The following is a reasonable guess in view of Busemann's results (it's probably known to be true):

Suppose that $M$ is a connected Riemannian surface. Then the following are equivalent:

(a) the bisector of every geodesic segment in $M$ contains a (nondegenerate) geodesic subsegment.

(b) $M$ has constant curvature.

The direction (b)$\Rightarrow$(a) is well-known and easy to prove. Even more: Under the constant curvature assumption, the bisector is a geodesic graph in $M$.

Comment: Beautiful characterization. Thank you, I still have a super weak intuition with Riemannian Surfaces.