# Are half spaces in Hadamard manifold geodesically convex?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, geodesic

Given a Hadamard manifold $M$ (complete, simply connected and of nonpositive curvature) and two points $x,y\in M$ I want to consider the half space $H(x,y)=\{z\in M\mid d(x,z)\leq d(z,y)\}$. I wonder whether $H(x,y)$ is geodesically convex, i.e. if $\gamma\colon \mathbb R \to M$ is a geodesic with $\gamma(0)\in H(x,y)$ and $\gamma(t_0)\in H(x,y)$ for some $t_0>0$ then $\gamma(t)\in H(x,y)$ for all $t\in[0,t_0]$. I feel like this should be true as I checked the examples of the hyperbolic plane and $\mathbb R^n$.
I kind of understand that the function $t\mapsto d(x,\gamma(t))$ is convex, so that the metric ball is geodesically convex. But I don't know how this helps here since we have to consider the difference of two such functions.

Comment: The halfspaces defined in Definition $6$ [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjswNDn27b2AhXhwQIHHT7JCFgQFnoECA0QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1804.10738&usg=AOvVaw2qT_ReDa1bDGGBK8gSH6-n) are not convex sets in the general setting. Are they geodesically convex?

Comment: There is a theorem saying that if all bisecting hypersurfaces are totally geodesic, then the manifold has constant sectional curvature.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think that their definition of convex is identical with my definition of geodesically convex.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do you have a reference for this theorem?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348654/do-equidistant-points-form-a-geodesic-in-the-torus/4349457#4349457).